# How to change the update behavior of jquery datatable cell?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery datatable to display some information. The update functionality is working fine. When I double click on a cell value to edit, it becomes a textbox. It allows me enter whatever value I want and press enter key. Once I press the enter key, it is sending an AJAX request to the server to perform the update. I was trying to find out if there is a way to do the update when I press tab key (instead of enter key) or click on a different cell. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at blur or focusout? http://api.jquery.com/focusout/ http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: Thank you. There is an onblur option for the jquery datatable.